# discrete logarithm vs normal logarithm

Tags: discrete-logarithm, number-theory, group-theory

Crypto schemes normally use discrete logarithm instead of normal logarithm.
I think this has to do  with the fact that discrete logarithm is hard to solve while normal logarithm isn't.
Can someone explain why discrete logarithm is hard to solve and normal one isn't?

Comment: it seems I can't comment hence answer. Question Marc linked as duplicate isn't a duplicate because answer in that question doesn't explain why the discrete logarithm is hard and normal isn't.
Please read questions more carefully next time Marc.

Comment: [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/39902/706) is another question for which this one could possibly be closed as a duplicate of.